# Let "expandedness" pass through when wrapping a widget in another?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I created a wrapper Widget for easily creating checkboxes with a leading Widget which is optionally clickable:

```
class MyCheckbox extends StatelessWidget{
  final Widget leading;
  final bool leadingClickable;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged onChanged;

  const MyCheckbox({Key key, this.leading, this.leadingClickable, this.value, this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    if( leading != null ){ 
      children.add(
        leadingClickable 
          ? InkWell(
            child: leading, 
            onTap: onChanged == null ? null : () => onChanged(!value)
          ) 
          : leading
        );
    }
    children.add(Checkbox(value: value, onChanged: onChanged));

    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: children
    );
  }

}
```

Now, let's say I use it like this:

```
  return MyCheckbox(
    leading: Expanded(child: Text('Tap here to check the checkbox')),
    leadingClickable: true,
    value: myValue,
    onChanged: (){
      // Do stuff
    }
  );
```

As you can see, I pass a `Text` wrapped in an `Expanded` as `leading`. But because `MyCheckbox` wraps `leading` in an `InkWell`, the `Expanded` gets lost, and the text doesn't fill all available space.

If I pass `leadingClickable = false`, it works as expected because `leading` is not wrapped in an `InkWell`.

So, what's the best way to let the "expandedness" pass through even when wrapping a widget in another one? I guess I could check if `leading is Expanded`, but that seems like a hacky way to do it.

Comment: I'd delegate the Expanded to the Checkbox widget, so you wrap the InkWell with Expanded inside the checkbox, and then simply pass Text to leading

Comment: @contrasting Sure, that's an obvious way to "solve" it. But it leads to inevitable headache down the road the day you want a checkbox with a non-expanded `leading` widget... I'd prefer to let the user code decide if the `leading` widget should be expanded or not. Same principle as having it be a `Widget` instead of forcing it to be a `Text` and just pass a `string` to `MyCheckbox` - the day will come when you want something else than a `Text` there...

Comment: so going by your argument, why not just pass the InkWell too, instead of having leadingClickable :) if you want configurability, go all the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just add whether to expand the leading or not as a variable to MyCheckbox, so you get something like

```
return MyCheckbox(
  leading: Text('Tap here to check the checkbox'),
  leadingClickable: true,
  expandLeading: true,
  value: myValue,
  onChanged: (){
    // Do stuff
  }
);
```

The implementation would have something like

```
if( leading != null ) {
  final tempLeading = leadingClickable 
      ? InkWell(
        child: leading, 
        onTap: () => onChanged?.call(!value) 
      : leading;
  final expLeading = expandLeading ?
      Expanded(child: tempLeading) : tempLeading;
  children.add(expLeading);
}
```

And you probably want to give the constructor a default value for expandLeading:

```
const MyCheckbox({
  Key key,
  this.leading,
  this.leadingClickable,
  this.expandLeading = false,
  this.value,
  this.onChanged,
}) : super(key: key);
```